# How to parse a complicated string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to figure out the best way to parse a complex JSON object stored as a string in SQL Server.

My table has the following information:

```
LogID      |    Content
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
55271413   |    {"LicensePlate":"","FreightHaulerProviderXId":"ABC","FreightProviderReferenceNumber":"5218912","CarrierScac":"XYZ","Latitude":33.595555,"Longitude":-85.854722,"StreetAddress1":"","StreetAddress2":"","City":"","State":"","PostalCode":"","Country":""}
55271414   |    {"LicensePlate":"","FreightHaulerProviderXId":"ABC","FreightProviderReferenceNumber":"5218944","CarrierScac":"XYZ","Latitude":37.996666,"Longitude":-78.314444,"StreetAddress1":"","StreetAddress2":"","City":"","State":"","PostalCode":"","Country":""}
55271415   |    {"LicensePlate":"","FreightHaulerProviderXId":"ABC","FreightProviderReferenceNumber":"5219079","CarrierScac":"YZB","Latitude":34.027500,"Longitude":-117.522222,"StreetAddress1":"","StreetAddress2":"","City":"","State":"","PostalCode":"","Country":""}
55271416   |    {"LicensePlate":"","FreightHaulerProviderXId":"ABC","FreightProviderReferenceNumber":"5219020","CarrierScac":"XYZ","Latitude":37.754722,"Longitude":-121.144166,"StreetAddress1":"","StreetAddress2":"","City":"","State":"","PostalCode":"","Country":""}
55271417   |    {"LicensePlate":"","FreightHaulerProviderXId":"ABC","FreightProviderReferenceNumber":"5218911","CarrierScac":"XYZ","Latitude":40.585833,"Longitude":-91.425000,"StreetAddress1":"","StreetAddress2":"","City":"","State":"","PostalCode":"","Country":""}
55271418   |    {"LicensePlate":"","FreightHaulerProviderXId":"ABC","FreightProviderReferenceNumber":"5218785","CarrierScac":"XYZ","Latitude":30.747500,"Longitude":-85.270277,"StreetAddress1":"","StreetAddress2":"","City":"","State":"","PostalCode":"","Country":""}
55271426   |    {"LicensePlate":"","FreightHaulerProviderXId":"ABC","FreightProviderReferenceNumber":"5219044","CarrierScac":"XYZ","Latitude":33.598333,"Longitude":-97.936388,"StreetAddress1":"","StreetAddress2":"","City":"","State":"","PostalCode":"","Country":""}
```

I'm trying to parse each string and place it inside a new column with the name of the JSON attribute as the column name, and the corresponding value as the row value.

For example, here would be the results I'm looking for below for each row:

```
LogID     |  LicensePlate  |  FreightHaulerProviderXId  |  FreightProviderReferenceNumber  |  CarrierScac  |  Latitude  |  Longitude  |  StreetAddress1  |  StreetAddress2  |  City  |  State  |  PostalCode  |  Country
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
55271413  |                |  ABC                       |  5218912                         |  XYZ          |  33.595555 |  -85.854722 |                  |                  |        |         |              |
```

I've tried parsing it using some probably pretty bad SQL logic. Essentially I look for the entire string, grab a sub-string, and then manually assign a column name. This isn't a very good solution for scalability and performance.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    SUBSTRING(lcon.Content, CHARINDEX('CarrierScac', lcon.Content)+14, CHARINDEX('City',lcon.Content) - CHARINDEX('CarrierScac', lcon.Content) + Len('City')-21) as 'CarrierScac',
    SUBSTRING(lcon.Content, CHARINDEX('Latitude', lcon.Content)+10, CHARINDEX('Longitude',lcon.Content) - CHARINDEX('Latitude', lcon.Content) + Len('Longitude')-21) as 'Latitude',
    SUBSTRING(lcon.Content, CHARINDEX('Longitude', lcon.Content)+11, CHARINDEX('PositionEventType',lcon.Content) - CHARINDEX('Longitude', lcon.Content) + Len('"PositionEventType')-31) as 'Longitude'
FROM
    acg.LogContext lcon
WHERE
    lcon.Content LIKE '%XYZ%'
```

Any help would be appreciated as I seem to be completely stumped even after researching techniques for the better half of the day.

Thanks!

Comment: Starting in SQL Server 2016, JSON support is built into the database:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn921897.aspx.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the help of a parse function and two cross applies...

```
Declare @YourTable table (LogID int,Content varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(55271413,'{"LicensePlate":"","FreightHaulerProviderXId":"ABC","FreightProviderReferenceNumber":"5218912","CarrierScac":"XYZ","Latitude":33.595555,"Longitude":-85.854722,"StreetAddress1":"","StreetAddress2":"","City":"","State":"","PostalCode":"","Country":""}'),
(55271414,'{"LicensePlate":"","FreightHaulerProviderXId":"ABC","FreightProviderReferenceNumber":"5218944","CarrierScac":"XYZ","Latitude":37.996666,"Longitude":-78.314444,"StreetAddress1":"","StreetAddress2":"","City":"","State":"","PostalCode":"","Country":""}'),
(55271415,'{"LicensePlate":"","FreightHaulerProviderXId":"ABC","FreightProviderReferenceNumber":"5219079","CarrierScac":"YZB","Latitude":34.027500,"Longitude":-117.522222,"StreetAddress1":"","StreetAddress2":"","City":"","State":"","PostalCode":"","Country":""}'),
(55271416,'{"LicensePlate":"","FreightHaulerProviderXId":"ABC","FreightProviderReferenceNumber":"5219020","CarrierScac":"XYZ","Latitude":37.754722,"Longitude":-121.144166,"StreetAddress1":"","StreetAddress2":"","City":"","State":"","PostalCode":"","Country":""}'),
(55271417,'{"LicensePlate":"","FreightHaulerProviderXId":"ABC","FreightProviderReferenceNumber":"5218911","CarrierScac":"XYZ","Latitude":40.585833,"Longitude":-91.425000,"StreetAddress1":"","StreetAddress2":"","City":"","State":"","PostalCode":"","Country":""}'),
(55271418,'{"LicensePlate":"","FreightHaulerProviderXId":"ABC","FreightProviderReferenceNumber":"5218785","CarrierScac":"XYZ","Latitude":30.747500,"Longitude":-85.270277,"StreetAddress1":"","StreetAddress2":"","City":"","State":"","PostalCode":"","Country":""}'),
(55271426,'{"LicensePlate":"","FreightHaulerProviderXId":"ABC","FreightProviderReferenceNumber":"5219044","CarrierScac":"XYZ","Latitude":33.598333,"Longitude":-97.936388,"StreetAddress1":"","StreetAddress2":"","City":"","State":"","PostalCode":"","Country":""}')


Select LogID
      ,LicensePlate = max(case when Item='LicensePlate' then Value else null end)
      ,FreightHaulerProviderXId = max(case when Item='FreightHaulerProviderXId' then Value else null end)
      ,FreightProviderReferenceNumber = max(case when Item='FreightProviderReferenceNumber' then Value else null end)
      ,CarrierScac = max(case when Item='CarrierScac' then Value else null end) 
      ,Latitude = max(case when Item='Latitude' then Value else null end)
      ,Longitude = max(case when Item='Longitude' then Value else null end)
      ,StreetAddress1 = max(case when Item='StreetAddress1' then Value else null end)
      ,StreetAddress2 = max(case when Item='StreetAddress2' then Value else null end)
      ,City = max(case when Item='City' then Value else null end)
      ,State = max(case when Item='State' then Value else null end)
      ,PostalCode = max(case when Item='PostalCode' then Value else null end)
      ,Country = max(case when Item='Country' then Value else null end)
 From ( 
        Select LogID
              ,Item  = max(case when RetSeq=1 then RetVal else null end)
              ,Value = max(case when RetSeq=2 then RetVal else null end)
        From (
                Select A.LogID
                      ,Grp = B.RetSeq
                      ,C.*
                From  @YourTable A
                Cross Apply (Select RetSeq,RetVal=Replace(Replace(Replace(RetVal,'"',''),'{',''),'}','') From [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](A.Content,',') ) B
                Cross Apply (Select * From [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](B.RetVal,':') ) C
            ) N Group By LogID,Grp
      ) F
 Group By LogID
```

Returns

[image]

---

The UDF if needed

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From (Select x = Cast('<x>'+ Replace(@String,@Delimiter,'</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')
```

Comment: YOU ARE A GENIUS. Thank you SO MUCH! How on earth did you learn such amazing SQL skills? Is there a book/website/online course you would recommend?

Comment: @colonelsanders91  Genius... My wife will disagree.  Can only recommend "learn by doing", and by watching the heavy hitters on SO.  I learn something every day.  That's the fun part.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to upgrade to SQL Server 2016. Otherwise I would consider using Newtonsoft library with SQL CLR integration.

http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Comment: There are a huge number of sources that detail how SQL CLR is quite memory-leaky.  Has this been resolved?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot upgrade to 2016 nor do I have perms for any third-party integration to our databases :(

Answer (score 0):

JSON...  Seems like CLR is favored by most folks; but here is an interesting TSQL approach.

I know it's not polite to post just a link here, but this might be TL;DR for most folks; and as @Gordon Linoff mentions, 2016 will have built-in support.  So anyway, here is *a* solution somebody has come-up with:

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/